# Regex for routing multiple urls Express

Tags: regex, express, routes

I'm trying to route multiple wild card urls to the same function in express. I think I need some sort of regex, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I want do something like this:

```
app.route(['scripts/*', 'styles/*', 'images/*']).get(handler);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do it:

```
app.route('/:url(api|components|scripts|styles|bower_components|images)/*')
   .get(errors[404]);
```